# AFNetworking + current reachable interface

Tags: ios5, reachability, afnetworking

I have a `UITableView` showing a list downloads located on my own server. Each row has its own download button. Since some of them have a size greater than 50Mb I would like to disable their download button to save user money and experience **when they are under 3G only (WWAN)**. 
I'm already using **AFNetowrking** and I know that they plan to support flags for current reachable interfaces in [some experimental branch on github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/experimental-expanded-network-reachability), but I prefer to use that code only when it become stable production/ready code. 
I need something like 3 kind of status:

- Not Reachable
- Reachable via WWAN
- Reachable via WiFi

How can I accomplish my goal with just **AFNetworking**? Do I have to add another library?

**NOTE:** i'va already a lot of working code deployed into this app, most of it relies on **AFNetworking** so replacing this library, couldn't be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold tight for a few more days. I'll have that pushed out by the end of the week :)

Edit: 1.0RC1 is now merged into master. Enjoy!